# October CMS : URL of the posts not set on the blogposts component

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, blogs, octobercms

I'm working on a non profit's website and we're using October CMS and its blog plug-in to add publications to it. The problem is, when displayed on the /publications page, the posts title link to the same page instead of their specific post's page (/publications/post/:slug) despite having specified the page to the component inspector. Nonetheless, typing the correct link (e.g. /publications/post/first-blog-post) still redirects to the correct page, so I guess it's something to do with RainLab's interpretation ? I tried setting the link to a 404 or any other page, it stays as /publications.

Has anybody ever encountered this problem and/or knows how to solve it ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set all of the settings?

See this screenshot:

[image: RainLab.Blog Component]

It's very important to set **post page** and **post slug**.